# Unable to load ChartArea, ChartSeries from kendo-react-all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I am trying to run an example to display a chart create using in Kendo React.

The example is on this tutorial:
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/charts/chart/elements/chart-area/

I have made a few changes to be able to run it via browser, without installing npm packages locally. However, I am unable to display this. I get an error in the console

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ChartContainer`. at ChartContainer

What am I missing??

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.jsa/15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-date-math/dist/cdn/js/kendo-date-math.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-drawing/dist/cdn/js/kendo-drawing.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-licensing/dist/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-react-intl/dist/cdn/js/kendo-react-intl.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-react-all/dist/cdn/js/kendo-react-all.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css">
      </head>
      <body>

        <div id="mydiv"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
        const data = [1, 2, 3, 5]
        const Chart = window.KendoReactAll.Chart
        const ChartArea = window.KendoReactAll.ChartArea
        const ChartSeries = window.KendoReactAll.ChartSeries
        const ChartSeriesItem = window.KendoReactAll.ChartSeriesItem
        
        const ChartContainer = () => (
          <Chart>
            <ChartArea background="#eee" margin={30} />
            <ChartSeries>
              <ChartSeriesItem data={data} name="Fibonacci" />
            </ChartSeries>
          </Chart>
        );
        
        ReactDOM.render(<ChartContainer />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
        </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this snipped is failing is because ChartArea, ChartSeries and ChartSeriesItem are not found on the kendo-react-all library. You need to import kendo-react-chart.js.

https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-react-charts/dist/cdn/js/kendo-react-charts.js

Also, you need to change the source module from `window.KendoReactAll` to `window.KendoReactCharts`

At the end it should look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.jsa/15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-date-math/dist/cdn/js/kendo-date-math.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-drawing/dist/cdn/js/kendo-drawing.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-licensing/dist/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-react-intl/dist/cdn/js/kendo-react-intl.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-react-all/dist/cdn/js/kendo-react-all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-react-charts/dist/cdn/js/kendo-react-charts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="mydiv"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    const data = [1, 2, 3, 5]
    const Chart = window.KendoReactCharts.Chart
    const ChartArea = window.KendoReactCharts.Chart
    const ChartSeries = window.KendoReactCharts.ChartSeries
    const ChartSeriesItem = window.KendoReactCharts.ChartSeriesItem
    
    const ChartContainer = () => (
      <Chart>
        <ChartArea background="#eee" margin={30} />
        <ChartSeries>
          <ChartSeriesItem data={data} name="Fibonacci" />
        </ChartSeries>
      </Chart>
    );
    
    ReactDOM.render(<ChartContainer />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works like expected. I thought that I could extract any class from kendo-react-all as indicated on its name. Good to know.